# DotNetNuke TabOrder chanage after edit tab

Tags: dotnetnuke

How to reproduce problem :

1. Install Clean Dnn Version : ***09.01.01 (129)***
2. Login as Host
3. Click ***Add Multiple Pages*** from ***Content / Pages***
4. In ***bulk pages to add*** write 5 lines... eg: Page1, Page2, Page3, Page4, Page5 (each in new line) and click ***add pages***
5. At this point everything work as expected. All Tabs are in order I typed it.
6. After This if I go to ***content / pages***
7. Click on ***settings icon*** of ***Page1***
8. Select ***Permissions*** and checked ***All users*** / ***VIEW*** and than ***Save***

Now there is a problem. The order of pages change to:

***HOME / Page2 / Page3 / Page4 / Page5 / Page1***

I monitor browser console and did not see any errors

step 1 : https://ibb.co/jdmktm

step 2 : https://ibb.co/b1yLR6

step 3 : https://ibb.co/cbhfR6   (add pages)

step 4 : https://ibb.co/kOh3eR

step 5 : https://ibb.co/hZoFtm

step 6 : https://ibb.co/b3b1Ym   (change permission on page 1)

step 7 : https://ibb.co/bLMqR6   (wrong order of changed page)

step 8 : https://ibb.co/jCZAR6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the same bug reported here:

https://dnntracker.atlassian.net/browse/DNN-10367?jql=text%20~%20%22TabOrder%22

And the error is corected in dnn 9.2

====================================

EDIT:

unfortunately after testing with 9.2 the problem is not solved...

EDIT2:

The problem is fixed in last build

I have problems with my building the sources and if i take build from dnn it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  I had that issue on an earlier version of DNN9 and upgraded to 9.1.1, which fixed the problem   Make sure you report it, and include screen shots to prove it.

Comment: I tested again with 9.1.1 and make screen shots and it don't work OK. (I will post screens later)

Comment: Then I try to install clean latest 9.2.0 from git source but after installer finished I get error : No sites currently exist for this installation. - 503 Service Unavailable  (and site don't work) Yesterday I just make upgrade from 9.1.1 to 9.2.0 from git and site woked but the tab ordering has not working

Comment: Can someone give me some link for working installer for DNN920